# Checking for freetype2 error when installing php5.6 on arch linux

Tags: archlinux, php-5.6, freetype2

I'm trying to install PHP version 5.6.37 from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/php56/) using `makepkg -i` command, but when it reaches the moment to check for the "freetype2" it displays the error:

> checking for freetype2... configure: error: freetype-config not found.

I already have 7.2 installed, but I need the 5.6 for an older project, and as in Ubuntu, I intend to have both installed.

```
makepkg -i
==> Making package: php56 5.6.37-1 (Wed 12 Sep 2018 12:27:39 PM +08)
==> Checking runtime dependencies...
==> Checking buildtime dependencies...
==> Retrieving sources...
  -> Found php-5.6.37.tar.xz
  -> Found php-5.6.37.tar.xz.asc
  -> Found php.ini.patch
  -> Found apache.conf
  -> Found php-fpm.conf.in.patch
  -> Found logrotate.d.php-fpm
  -> Found php-fpm.service
  -> Found php-fpm.tmpfiles
  -> Found use-enchant2.patch
  -> Found php-freetype-2.9.1.patch
==> Validating source files with sha512sums...

[...]

checking whether to enable truetype string function in GD... yes
checking whether to enable JIS-mapped Japanese font support in GD... no
If configure fails try --with-vpx-dir=<DIR>
checking for jpeg_read_header in -ljpeg... yes
checking for png_write_image in -lpng... yes
checking for XpmFreeXpmImage in -lXpm... yes
checking for pkg-config... (cached) no
checking for freetype2... configure: error: freetype-config not found.
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in build().
    Aborting...
```

Installing `freetype2` with Pacman didn't solve it.

Answer (score 7):

ln -s /usr/bin/pkg-config /usr/bin/freetype-config

and in PKGBUILD

--with-freetype-dir=no \